# How to get my app current version from Microsoft Store using Rest Api?

Tags: uwp, version

I tried the [Microsoft Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/get-product-details), but I don't know my sku id.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Every product in the Store has at least one SKU, and each SKU has at least one availability. An SKU is a specific version of a product with its own description, price, and other unique product details. Each app or add-on has a default SKU.

If you want to get the SKU of an app or add-on product, you could use [StoreContext.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getstoreproductforcurrentappasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync) to get a [StoreProduct Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproduct?view=winrt-20348) which represents the current app. Each SKU in the Store has a corresponding [StoreSku object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storesku?view=winrt-20348). Every StoreProduct Object has a Skus property you can use to access the SKUs for the product.

For more detailed information about SKU, please check: [Products, SKUs, and availabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#products-skus-and-availabilities)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out what's the **currently installed app's version number** from within the code of that app, you don't need to reach MS Store servers at all. You can get that from [package info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package?view=winrt-20348) like so:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
...
PackageVersion packageVersion = Package.Current.Version;
```